# Where do I find foreign keyboard sets in inDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, shortcuts

I am running an English version of inDesign with a german keyboard. Unfortunately, some of the shortcuts don’t work, due to the QUERTZ keyboard layout.

If I remember correctly, the English version of inDesign supported keyboard layouts for other languages, but it does not seem like that anymore.

Is there any way to get them back without first installing the German version, saving the default German keyboard shortcuts, only to install the English version again and paste them in there? Is there any resource, where I can get the shortcut set without going through all of this?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of shortcut keys of US (or English) software versions are unusable in this layout. This doesn't concern shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. You could change those anyway if you need to but, shortcuts for manipulating the shapes when creating a star or spiral and stuff like that can't be changed.

So your best option is just creating custom menus and shortcuts. [This Adobe page is a good reference to get you going.](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/customize-menus-keyboard-shortcuts.html)